# Recording decent sound

Tags: lavalier, microphone

Hi all i will be doing a shoot soon that will involve me recording dialogue of actors riding on a very speedy motor bike in the middle of a very busy street in my town and am wondering if i use the radio mics they will clip and i cannot use the boom mic... do you guys have an idea of how i can get decent sound in such a situation? thanks

Comment: How fast is very speedy? Are they wearing helmets? What type of shot does the DOP need?

Answer (score 1):

Why will the radio mics clip?  If you do a test before the take, you should be able to set a level that won't clip.  If you are worried about the radio mics going out of range then you can always strap a mini recorder to the bike and hardwire a mic to the recorder.

Answer (score 1):

+1 Iains comment.
I'd also say though if they are wearing helmets each(and you cannot see the actors mouths moving)-surely you can just wildtrack/ADR the lines afterwards? If it is not a close up shot either you'll get away with wildtrack I expect.

Otherwise-turn down the sensitivity of your radio mics, consider planting mics if you want the pass by of the motorbike and cross your fingers!